# Django - How to allow registration only for predefined list of e-mails/usernames

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a following simple view in my views.py for registration on my django site:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.succes(request, ('You have registered'))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

That approach would allow anyone to register but I want to allow only selected people to be able to register. I have a simple model for my database

```
class EmailList(models.Model):
    email_addres = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email_addres
```

with some e-mail addreses (my site doesn't have usernames, your username is an email addres) and I want to allow registration only for email addresses that are in that database. How would I perform such check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a functionality in Django that limits an access to users that pass a certain test: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test

You need to create a test function (verifying that the user is in allowed users list), and then use user_passes_test decorator on the view. In case you are using class based views, you need to use a **UserPassesTestMixin**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code works properly, just grab the contents of the AllowedUsers model and check whether the username is in the queryset.

**models.py**

```
class AllowedUsers(models.Model):
    allowed_email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.allowed_email
```

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = form.save(commit=False)
            allowed_emails = [user.allowed_email for user in AllowedUsers.objects.all()]
            if object['username'] in allowed_emails:
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, ('You have registered'))
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
```

I should say that if it were me, I'd be doing this while overriding the `form_valid` method of the default `LoginView`

Alternative **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.forms import ValidationError

class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        allowed_emails = [user.allowed_email for user in AllowedUsers.objects.all()]
        if form.cleaned_data['username'] in allowed_emails:
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            self.add_error('username', ValidationError("The provided username is not allowed"))
```